# Http to https redirect with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect http to https on an AWS server.

I tried the following htaccess syntax, nothing works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

And

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The website still loads with http, how can I fix that?

Comment: `AllowOveride All` - this is activated, yes?

Comment: @Lag I think this is his problem.

Comment: If you change `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` to `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on` do you get a redirect loop?

Comment: @Lag thank you, that was it :)

Comment: No problem - if in doubt blame configuration lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will 301 redirect all http links to https

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} Off [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If you want your site to also force www use this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} Off [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Edit:

Mod_rewrite is disabled by default on AWS. You need to enable it in your httpd.conf file beneath the following line: `/var/www/html` change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` and restart Apache.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, however, this still doesn't work for me, here is a screenshot http://prntscr.com/gi4rgm  neither www to non www works nor the http to https.

Comment: There's probably a configuration problem on the AWS side. Have a look at this to enable mod_rewrite https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=265770

Comment: Make an edit to your answer @KeesSonnema about the configuration issue. Will make your answer more relevant then :)